# Spatial query, embed in layer or project

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

I have 2 vector layers:

1) Polygons with parcel-boundaries

2) Polygon with project-boundaries

I want to query all the parcels that are within the project-area, using spatial query 'select parcels that intersect project-area'. 
Works fine, so far no problem.

The parcel-layer however is a layer that is often subject to changes.
Instead of always renewing the spatial query, I want to embed the query in a layer or project. So that every time when I open the layer/project, I automatticaly get the current parcels within the project-area.

Can this be done in QGIS?
In Mapinfo it was very easy but I'm walking over to Qgis, so it would be great not to lose this ability!

Comment: I assume you're using Shapefiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using shapefiles, you can create a layer that is a 'memory spatial view' with the QGIS DB Manager.

If I have schools and neighborhoods, they show up as Virtual Layers in the QGIS DB Manager. I can create a query that only shows me the points within a particular neighborhood with this query:

[image]

Here's the SQL:

```
select 
sch.name
, n."NBHD_ID"
, sch.geometry
from 'schools' as sch
join 'neighborhoods'as n on ST_Intersects(sch.geometry, n.geometry)
where  n."NBHD_ID" = '41'
```

Now at the bottom of the DB Manager is the 'load as new layer' option. To get your query to save as a virtual layer, enable these settings:

[image]

Now in my map, the virtual layer shows up with the points defined in the query:

[image]

Now save this QGIS document.

**Note**: you might need the **Memory Layer Saver** plugin enabled.

So I did a test where in a new QGIS document I created a new school point in the same NHood my spatial 'view' queries. Sure enough when I opened up the QGIS document with the spatial view layer, the new point showed up!

I think this would work just fine for what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Jonas Great! If you could mark that as your answer, I'd appreciate it!