# QGIS Spatial query (joining two layers)

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

I have two shapefiles. One is a point layer of trees, the other is a polygon of cadastral boundaries. I want to spatially join these two layers so that I get the information, on which cadastral boundary the tree lies. For every point of trees, I want to add the information of the boundaries to the trees in the query.

I have seen something similar here, but I'm not a big SQL expert :-)

[Spatial query, embed in layer or project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220888/spatial-query-embed-in-layer-or-project?rq=1)

Perhaps somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `Join attributes by location` tool to join the point data with the polygon boundary data that you have.

You can find the tool from `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attributes by location`, as you can see below:

[image]